# Meteor client function not passing data to server function for Accounts.createUser

Tags: meteor

I've a client function for registering a user that passes a data object to the server to create a user. I see the data object fully on the client side, yet when the server function runs (`registerNewUser`) it fails with an error saying the data is undefined.

On the client, **register.js**:

```
if (Meteor.isClient){

    Template.registrationStep2.events({

        'submit form': function(e, template) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (Session.get("registrationInstitutionID") && Session.get("registrationInstitutionRole")) {

                var data = [];

                var institutionID = template.find('#institutionID').value;
                var institutionRole = template.find('#institutionRole').value;
                var institutionName = template.find('#institutionName').value;

                data.login = template.find('#login').value;
                console.log("login: " + data.login);

                var firstName = template.find('#firstName').value;
                console.log("firstName: " + firstName);
                var lastName = template.find('#lastName').value;
                console.log("lastName: " + lastName);

                data.email = template.find('#email').value;
                console.log("email: " + data.email);
                data.password = template.find('#password').value;

                data.profile = {
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    role: institutionRole,
                    institutionID: institutionID
                }

                Meteor.call('registerNewUser', data, function(error, result){
                    Meteor.log.trace("User Data Object", data);
                    console.log(data);
                    if(error){
                        console.log("error", error);
                        Meteor.log.error("Error Creating User", error);
                    }
                    if(result){
                        console.log("SUCCESS adding user.");
                        Meteor.log.error("Success Result", result);

                        Session.set("flashType", "success");
                        Session.set("flashMessage", "Your account has been created.");

                        Router.go('registrationComplete');
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // alert("Need institution");
                $('#needInstitutionModal').modal('show');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the **server.js**:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'registerNewUser': function(data) {
        Meteor.log.debug("User Data Object on Server", data);
        console.log(data);
        return Accounts.createUser({
            username: data.login,
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
            profile: data.profile
    }
});
```

If I hardcode values for the createUser function all works OK. But when I use the data object I get errors like this for each field. (And I know from a console log the data object existed in the client before calling the server function).

Here is the specific error line in case it's hard to see below: **`Exception while invoking method 'registerNewUser' Error: Match error: Expected string, got undefined in field username`**

Here's the relevant output from the log:

```
I20150710-07:56:51.072(-5)? (07:56:51) [DEBUG @ programs/server/packages/ostrio_loggerconsole.js:67] - Object: 
I20150710-07:56:51.072(-5)? {
I20150710-07:56:51.072(-5)?     "time": "2015-07-10T12:56:51.070Z",
I20150710-07:56:51.072(-5)?     "level": "DEBUG",
I20150710-07:56:51.072(-5)?     "message": "User Data Object on Server",
I20150710-07:56:51.072(-5)?     "additional": []
I20150710-07:56:51.072(-5)? }
I20150710-07:56:51.075(-5)? logging data object on server ================+
I20150710-07:56:51.075(-5)? []
I20150710-07:56:51.077(-5)? Exception while invoking method 'registerNewUser' Error: Match error: Expected string, got undefined in field username
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at checkSubtree (/Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/check.js:177:13)
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at /Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/check.js:314:9
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/underscore.js:147:22)
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at checkSubtree (/Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/check.js:308:5)
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at check (/Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/check.js:50:5)
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at createUser (/Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/accounts-password.js:795:3)
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at Object.Accounts.createUser (/Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/accounts-password.js:875:10)
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.registerNewUser (app/server/server.js:17:25)
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at [object Object].methodMap.(anonymous function) (/Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:2536:30)
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (/Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp.js:2445:12)
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at /Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp.js:1476:20
I20150710-07:56:51.078(-5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:989:17)
I20150710-07:56:51.079(-5)?     at /Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp.js:1475:41
I20150710-07:56:51.079(-5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:989:17)
I20150710-07:56:51.079(-5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (/Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp.js:1474:51)
I20150710-07:56:51.079(-5)?     at /Users/srichardson/AppDevNew/ve-client-new/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:2425:38
I20150710-07:56:51.079(-5)? Sanitized and reported to the client as: Match failed [400]
```

Thanks much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you declare data as an array when you use it as an object.

Try

```
var data = {};
```

instead.

I just tried making a barebones version of this myself and I get the same problem as you when I declare it as an array which is interesting.

On the client everything looks normal (It forgoes data being an array once you start using keys) but on the server as far as it is concerned data is an empty array. Weird result but declaring data as an object fixed it.

Comment: Wow. That was it. Don't know what I was thinking but I missed it. Thanks for pointing it out. Interesting problem, true.